# PyQT5: How to line up button with line edit in a form row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a class that will generate all my widgets. Currently, I'm stuck because I want to make my line edit line up with the button (typical of what you see in file upload windows) but the button is in the next line. How do I line them up?

Class that generates the form widgets:

```
class CreateFormElements(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateFormElements, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_form_row(self, label, fieldType, *args, **kwargs):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        # this arguments will tell me if I want a button, and if the button should open a file window
        connectType = kwargs.get('connectType', None)
        _fieldType = kwargs.get('_fieldType', None)
        # if this is a button that should open up a file window, call the create_file_window() function to make a
        # file window. currently no button is visible and the file window is opening up directly.
        if connectType == 'file' and _fieldType == 'button':
            filePath = layout.addWidget(QLineEdit())
            fieldType.setText("Browse")
            fieldType.clicked.connect(create_file_window)

        layout.addRow(QLabel(label), fieldType)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Main window:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.myWindow()

    def myWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")
        sizeObject = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)
        print(" Screen size : " + str(sizeObject.height()) + "x" + str(sizeObject.width()))

        self.width = 600
        self.height = 480
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        elm = CreateFormElements()
        elm.create_form_row("Object Name: ", QPushButton(), connectType='file', _fieldType='button')
        layout.addWidget(elm)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the `QLineEdit` and `QButton` in a `QHBoxLayout`, and add that to your form layout, e.g.

```
lineEdit = QLineEdit()
fieldType.setText("Browse")

hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
hlayout.addWidget(lineEdit)
hlayout.addWidget(fieldType)

layout.addRow(label, hlayout)
```